# I don't quite get a javascript syntax about passing arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, parameters, arguments

My code:

```
const users = [ { id: 1, name: 'user1' }, { id: 2, name: 'user2' } ]

p = new Promise( resolve => resolve(users) )

p.then( (user) => console.log(user) )
```

Return me the following logs:

> > [ { id: 1, name: 'user1' }, { id: 2, name: 'user2' } ]

If I change it as below,

```
users.then( ([user]) => console.log(user) )
```

I receive the following logs:

> > { id: 1, name: 'user1' }

I don't quite understand why the second one only logs the first element in the array.

Comment: `users.then( ([user1, user2]) => console.log(user1, user2) )` - this logs both the users.

Comment: Because `[user]` used the way you have it is destructing and that says to get the first item from the array and given it a name of `user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html) is an **ES6** aka **ECMA2015** features.

You can destructure `Array` and `Objects`.

---

`Object` destructuring as bellow, allow you to pick up the `keys` you want to get from an `object` using easy syntax.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
};

// Without object destructuring
const a_ = obj.a;
const b_ = obj.b;


// With object destructuring
const {
  a,
  b,
} = obj;

console.log(a);
```

---

`Array` destructuring is quite the same, but instead of specifying the `keys` you want to get, you use the `index` of the data.

```js
const arr = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
];

// Without array destructuring
const a_ = arr[0];
const c_ = arr[2];

// With array destructuring
const [
  a, , c,
] = arr;

console.log(c);
```

---

You can use `Array` and `Object` destructuring anywhere; including in function parameters. It's especially good in this case because you can assign `default` value easily to `keys`, as bellow

```js
function func({
  a,
  b,
  c = 'default',
}) {
  console.log(a, '/', b, '/', c);
}

func({
  a: 'j\'aime la france',
  b: 'vive les baguettes',
});
```

Comment: Awesomeeee I totally got it now. Thank you for giving many examples

Answer (score 4):

It's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
[a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(c)
```

but if you only destructure one, you get the first value of the array

```js
[a] = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(a)
```

As for your example, destructuring can be done in many places such as function arguments

Comment: Thank you for a simple, but very useful answer